# batch start path\this file's file name

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

The title is kinda vague, I was not sure how to word it.

how would I do this.
start path\file name of running file.

Kinda like start path\%0 that is kinda what I am trying to do but if I do that it will come up with something like the bellow.

copy C:\Users\username\Desktop\folder\C:\Users\username\Desktop\batch.bat

I just want C:\Users\username\Desktop\folder\batch.bat
batch.bat being the file name, this must change if you rename the batch file.

Sorry if I explained this badly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with some `for` trickery:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
echo %0
for %%f in (%0) do set basename=%%~nf
echo Will run \arbitrary-path\%basename%
endlocal
```

The `%%~nf` gives you the name of the `%%f` variable, without path or extension. If you run it with something like:

```
C:\Users\Pax\qq.cmd
```

you will see something like:

```
c:\Users\Pax\qq.cmd
Will run \arbitrary-path\qq
```

You can see all the *other* useful expansions if you type `for /?` into your command window:

```
    %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding
                  quotes (")
    %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path
                  name
    %~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
    %~pI        - expands %I to a path only
    %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
    %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
    %~sI        - expanded path contains short names
                  only
    %~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
    %~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
    %~zI        - expands %I to size of file
    %~$PATH:I   - searches the directories listed in
                  the PATH environment variable and
                  expands %I to the fully qualified
                  name of the first one found. If the
                  environment variable name is not
                  defined or the file is not found by
                  the search, then this modifier
                  expands to the empty string
```

The modifiers can be combined to get compound results:

```
    %~dpI       - expands %I to a drive letter and
                  path only
    %~nxI       - expands %I to a file name and
                  extension only
    %~fsI       - expands %I to a full path name with
                  short names only
    %~dp$PATH:I - searches the directories listed in
                  the PATH environment variable for
                  %I and expands to the drive letter
                  and path of the first one found.
    %~ftzaI     - expands %I to a DIR like output line
```

Comment: Thanks.

for this code:
`@echo off
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in (%0) do set basename=%%~nf
set UsPr=%UserProfile%
copy %0 "%UsPr%"
start "%UsPr%\%basename%.bat"`

If this was used on a computer with CMD disabled, it would not work, when the 2nd batch file is opened using the start command it would come up with an error saying cmd is disabled, how could I get around this? And also how would it be stopped from opening its self an infinite amount of times over until your computer crashes/freezes?

Comment: @Neb9, if `cmd` is disabled, all bets are off. You can't run any command scripts surely. And, if you want to stop infinite regress simply add a check to ensure `\arbitrary-path\qq.cmd` is not the same as `%0`.

Comment: Sorry I am in-experienced at batch, how would I add the check you described? batch works if cmd is disabled, but you cannot start any batch files from a batch file using the start command.

Comment: Here is a check that I made, it does not work though?
`@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in (%0) do set basename=%%~nf
set UsPr=%UserProfile%
copy %0 "%UsPr%"
if %0=="%UsPr%\%basename%.bat" goto :1 
goto :2
:1
command
exit
:2
command
start "%UsPr%\%basename%.bat"` 
I should probably make a new thread for this.